# Need help altering modulus equation

Tags: java

I currently need to produce an array consisting of the following elements:

`-0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 0...`

and so on. This is my current code:

```
// Sequence: -0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, -0.5, 0, 0.5...
public static double[] generateI(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return null;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return new double[0];
    }
    double[] arr = new double[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = ((0.5 * i) % 2) - 0.5; \\need help here.
    }
    return arr;
}
```

However, my output is:

[-0.5, 0.0, 0.5, **1.0**, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, **1.0**, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, **1.0**].

Hence, my math equation is wrong.

**(note that I have tried using the `-Math.cos(i * Math.PI/2)/2` equation, and although it is a valid solution, I was tasked to do it using a modulus function in a single line of code.)**

Another sequence (for those interested) is:

`-0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5...`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `otherSequence` flag to change which of your two patterns you want to activate.

For the second pattern you've mentioned, you need to take the mod of `i` and `4` (to return `[0, 1, 2, 3]`) and then add the result of the integer division between `i` and `4` in order to make the sequence continue to the next 4 numbers (e.g. `i = 6` (`6 / 4  = 1 -> [1, 2, 3, 4]`)

```
class Main {
    public static double[] generateI(int n, boolean other_sequence) {
        if (n < 0) {
            return null;
        } else if (n == 0) {
            return new double[0];
        }
        double[] arr = new double[n];

        if (other_sequence) {
            Arrays.setAll(arr, i -> ((i % 4) + (i / 4)));
        } else {
            Arrays.setAll(arr, i -> ((i % 4) - 1) * ((i + 1) % 2) * 0.5);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(generateI(8, false)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(generateI(16, true)));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[-0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0]
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Comment: Good enough for this. Of course, in the real world, you would avoid a boolean parameter like that otherSequence thing (btw: naming: no "_" in java variable names, only in SOME_CONSTANT). Just have two different methods, with names that say what they are doing. `generateI()` doesnt say what the method does, and no human reader would later no what the point of otherSequence is. But for the purpose of such a homework, good enough.

Comment: @GhostCat I thought of refactoring it in an other method `generateJ()` or something like that but I thought the asker might wanted one function doing two things.

Comment: I really appreciate the code for the second sequence! Do you think you could engineer a single line statement for the first sequence?

Comment: Yeah! That's a great solution! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Sequence: -0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, -0.5, 0, 0.5...
public static double[] generateI(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return null;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return new double[0];
    }
    double[] arr = new double[n];
    //for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //    arr[i] = ((i % 3) - 1) * 0.5;
    //}
    Arrays.arr.setAll(i -> ((i % 3) - 1) * 0.5);
    // Correction, should be ((i%4)-1)*((i+1)%2)*0.5
    return arr;
}
```

There are 3 values, hence modulo 3. Then think how 0, 1, 2 should be mapped onto -0.5, 0, 0.5.

Nice is the [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll(double%5B%5D,java.util.function.IntToDoubleFunction)) class.

The other sequence I leave to your own efforts.

Comment: @knucklestheman yes, incorrect answer. `((i%4)-1)*((i+1)%2)*0.5`

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for! How did you approach solving the problem? Would really love to learn ways to approach problems such as this one.

Comment: Sequence of 4 = modulo 4. Inside every second 0, hence * modulo 2. Of course 0.5*sin(pi*0.5*i) would be nice too, the linear way

Answer (score 0):

There's much easier ways I think

```
private static final double[] doubleArray = new double[] {-0.5, 0, 0.5, 0};
    
    public static double[] generateI(int n) {
        var resArray = new double[n];

        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
            resArray[j] = doubleArray[j % 4];
        }
        
        return resArray;
    }
```